# How to define a SQL set operation in a grammar?

Tags: parsing, antlr, antlr4

I am having a tough time figuring out a way to handle the SQL set operation, that it, being able to do things like `query1 UNION ALL query2`. It should support the following statements:

```
select 1 union all select 2                                 -- ok
with cte as (select 1) select 1 from cte union all select 2 -- ok
(select 1 limit 1) union all select 1 union all (select 2)  -- ok
```

And should not support the following, as one of the table operands to the query expression needs to be parenthesized:

```
select 1 from cte union all with cte as (select 1)          -- no
select 1 limit 1 union select 1                             -- no
```

Here is the grammar I have so far:

```
 selectStatement:
     withClause?
     (selectStatementWithParens|selectClause|setOperation)
     orderClause?
     (limitClause offsetClause?)?
     ;

selectStatementWithParens
    : OPEN_PAREN selectStatement CLOSE_PAREN
    ;

selectClause:
    SELECT // a bunch of other stuff...
    ;

setOperation:
    (selectClause | selectStatementWithParens)
    (setOperand (selectClause | selectStatementWithParens))*
    ;

setOperand
    : UNION (DISTINCT|ALL)?
    | INTERSECT DISTINCT?
    | EXCEPT DISTINCT?
    ;
```

Though it does work -- it seems to be a bit heavy handed, and I don't like having the `selectStatementWithParens` underneath the `WITH` (though it does work, such the `WITH` is optional, and so it can support `(select 1)` or `(with x as (select 1) select 1))`. How could this be improved, or does it already look pretty good?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider this:

```
parser grammar DBParser
    ;
options {
    tokenVocab = DBLexer;
}

root: selectStatement SEMI? EOF;

selectStatement
    : selectClause # selectClauseStatement
    | selectStatement limitClause # limitedSelectStatement
    | OPEN_PAREN selectStatement CLOSE_PAREN # parenSelectStatement
    | selectStatement setOperand selectStatement # setOperationStatement
    ;

selectClause: SELECT NUMBER;

limitClause: LIMIT NUMBER;

setOperand: UNION ALL?;
```

It gives a usable parse tree (so far as I can tell) and has max K = 1

[image]

I may have missed some subtlety, but perhaps it puts you on a better path.

Comment: thanks again! How would you handle it if you had to keep the `with?` at the top of the `selectStatement` ?

Comment: actually, I've posted a follow-up question in regards to that where I get left-recursion when trying to incorporate that approach in.